# Birth/death model over time simulation

Tags: r, simulation, phylogeny

I'm trying to plot a graph that will show species number over time using a birth death model. So far all the packages and models I've seen will not allow me to input a starting number of species which is problematic as my extinction rate is higher than my speciation rate.
The data I have for this question is;
speciation rate (or b) is 0.0157
and extinction rate (or d) is 53.3.
starting number of species =250000.
currently I've tried using rbdtree and simbdtree.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you don't need the phylogenetic tree of the species that are generated, and just want to know the number of species over time, you don't really need a package for this: the code is fairly simple (if you know what equations to implement).

Also assuming that you want a *stochastic* simulation model.

Let's say for simplicity that you only want to know the numbers of species *at the times at which speciation or extinction events occur* (this is a little bit easier than figuring them out at equally spaced times). Let's say the *per capita* mutation/speciation/birth rate is `b` and the *per capita* death/extinction rate is `d` (it's fairly standard to assume these rates are constant *per capita*, you could make other assumptions if you wanted). Then if there are currently `s` species present, the total rate of events is `(b+d)*s`, and the probability that the next event is a birth is `b/(b+d)`. The time is exponentially distributed.

```r
num_events <- 1000000
s <- rep(NA, num_events+1)
t <- rep(NA, num_events+1)
t[1] <- 0
s[1] <- 250000
b <- 0.0157
d <- 53.3
set.seed(101)
for (i in 1:num_events) {
   if (s[i]==0) break ## stop if extinct
   delta_t <- rexp(1,rate=(b+d)*s[i])
   t[i+1] <- t[i] + delta_t
   if (runif(1)<(b/(b+d))) s[i+1] <- s[i]+1 else s[i+1] <- s[i]-1
}
plot(t,s,type="s",log="y")
curve(s[1]*exp((b-d)*x), add=TRUE, lwd=3, col=adjustcolor("red", alpha=0.4))
```

[image: birth-death curve]

You can see that until you get down to a few 100 individuals, it's barely worth bothering with a stochastic simulation — the theoretical exponential decay curve matches the population dynamics almost exactly when the numbers are large.

The code could easily be sped up a little bit, at some small cost to interpretability (but it should take not more than a few seconds at most).

Comment: Hi Ben, Thank you for your response it has been really helpful. I have taken the code you suggested and altered it a bit however I'm struggling to understand what time is showing on the scale (I'm aware this may be really simple and my brain is just on a blitz). To use your example would that put 0.05 at 5,000 years? I only ask as this is one of many graphs I'm creating for a comparison of species number over time (whereby the others produce different values of t, i.e. from 0.00 to 0.01. Thanks

Comment: The time axis has the same units as the units of `b` and `d`, whatever they are (you didn't specify).